# Why it can not find the implicit?

Tags: scala

I have the following definition in the file `Show.scala`:

```
package com.example

trait Show[A] {
  def show(a: A): String
}

object Show {
  def apply[A](implicit sh: Show[A]): Show[A] = sh

  //def show[A](a:A)(implicit  sh: Show[A]) = sh.show(a)
  def show[A: Show](a: A) = Show[A].show(a)

  implicit class ShowOps[A: Show](a: A) {
    def show = Show[A].show(a)
  }

  implicit val intCanShow: Show[Int] =
    new Show[Int] {
      override def show(a: Int): String = s"int $a"
    }

}
```

and in the `Main.scala`:

```
package com.example

object Main extends App {

  println(Show.show(344))
  println(30.show)
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
[error] /home/developer/scala/show/src/main/scala/com/example/Main.scala:6:14: value show is not a member of Int
[error]   println(30.show)
[error]              ^
[error] one error found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to `Main` to find `Show`, you need to `import Show._` in `Main.scala`

```
package com.example

object Main extends App {
  import Show._ 
  // Or import Show.ShowOps if you only want to use that implicit

  println(Show.show(344))
  println(30.show)
}
```

You can [Try it](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/fJDzDPw/0)

Here are the [implicits rules](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html#21.2) to keep in mind (From Martin's book):

Here is the relevant rule for your particular case (I have highlighted the relevant parts):

> **Scope Rule**: An inserted implicit conversion must be in **scope as a
>   single identifier**, or be associated with the source or target type of
>   the conversion. The Scala compiler will only consider implicit
>   conversions that are in scope. To make an implicit conversion
>   available, therefore, you must in some way bring it into scope.
>   Moreover, with one exception, the implicit conversion must be in scope
>   as a **single identifier**. The compiler will not insert a conversion of
>   the form someVariable.convert. For example, it will not expand x + y
>   to someVariable.convert(x) + y. If you want to make
>   someVariable.convert available as an implicit, therefore, you would
>   need to import it, which would make it available as a single
>   identifier. Once imported, the compiler would be free to apply it as
>   convert(x) + y. In fact, it is common for libraries to include a
>   Preamble object including a number of useful implicit conversions.
>   Code that uses the library can then do a single "import Preamble._" to
>   access the library's implicit conversions

Comment: Why do I need to import? It is in the same package.

Comment: There are rules for implicits to work, one of them is that you need to explicetely import them

Comment: @zero_coding The `implicit val` is inside `Show` so it is not directly visible outside that object (just like any other symbol inside an object or class).

Answer (score 5):

Try this one..

```
package com.example

import Show._ // add in order to access implicit..

object Main extends App {

  println(Show.show(344))
  println(30.show)
}
```